# Spring Boot - Java Mail - Couldn't connect to host

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, email, smtp

I've implemented the email manager using JavaMailSender into my Java application, configured with Gmail email, and locally tested.

I'm using a free domain by freenom.

in localhost on my pc everything working perfectly. But deploying on the server the application obtains this error:

```
c.m.a.m.components.EmailManager          : sendRegisterEmail Exception: Mail server connection failed; 
nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: 
Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com. Failed messages: 
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
```

**test done**

- Generating an application password
- Using directly the host IP
- Using port 465 and 25
- Disabling VPS firewall
- Used another mail provider

**application.properties**

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587

spring.mail.username=***********@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=***********

spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=false

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

spring.mail.mime.charset=UTF-8
spring.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
```

Comment: Have you tried manually setting a higher timeout value?

Comment: @SantiagoWagner No, so I tested adding spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000; spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000; spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000 - but never change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change spring.mail.port to 465. This might help.

Port **587** is technically **correct**. However, **many ESPs** have adopted implicit TLS **on port 465**.
Also, there's probably a  [firewall preventing you from connecting directly](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug), you may need to [connect through a proxy](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#proxy).

Comment: I've tried configuring the port to 465 but nothing changes. telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 and telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 work.

I also tested with firewall disabled, but the result is the same.

I'm going to study how to connect through a proxy, I take the test and tell you.